# Dynamic rendering of sections/divs according to an array of objects in React.JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an array of objects to show data on the web page and all the div should according to key in the array object (in this order).

```
var priceSize = <div>HTML goes here</div>
var agentDetails = <div>HTML goes here</div>
var mappedHouses = <div>HTML goes here</div>
var sideComps = <div>HTML goes here</div>
var priceDays = <div>HTML goes here</div>

render() {
 return (
 report_sequence.map((data) => 
 <div className={data.key}>
  {
   data.key === 1 ? subjectProperty : 
   data.key === 2 ? priceSize : 
   data.key === 4 ? priceDays : 
   data.key === 5 ? sideComps : 
   data.key === 6 ? mappedHouses : 
   data.key === 9 ? agentDetails : ''
  }
 </div>
 )
 );
}
```

This is my array :

```
var report_sequence = [
    {key : 1, value : "SUBJECT PROPERTY OVERVIEW"},
    {key : 2, value : "PRICE & SIZE GRAPH"},
    {key : 9, value : "AGENT SUMMARY"},
    {key : 4, value : "PRICE & DAYS ON MARKET GRAPH"},
    {key : 6, value : "MAPPED HOUSES"},
    {key : 5, value : "SIDE BY SIDE COMPARISION"}
   ]
```

I expect div arrangement according to my report sequence.
Please help for the same.

Comment: You're not returning anything from `render` for one thing. It's also not clear what your output should be. Do you want to sort by key, or just keep the order of the objects in the array?

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes just keep the order of the objects in the array.

Comment: Is the text in the value (e.g. `"SUBJECT PROPERTY OVERVIEW") meant to go in the "HTML goes here" part?

Comment: The "HTML goes here" part means the UI of my web page. It does not have any relation with value (e.g. "SUBJECT PROPERTY OVERVIEW") etc.

Comment: @ParvezSiddiqi you may find this library useful https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-floco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both approach will work fine for dynamic data rendering.

```
    return (
     report_sequence.map((data) => 
     <div className={data.key}>
      {
       data.key === 1 ? subjectProperty : 
       data.key === 2 ? priceSize : 
       data.key === 4 ? priceDays : 
       data.key === 5 ? sideComps : 
       data.key === 6 ? mappedHouses : 
       data.key === 9 ? agentDetails : ''
      }
     </div>
     )

//Second approach using switch according to Dacre Denny

   const renderItem = (key) => {
      switch(key) {
        case 1: return subjectProperty;
        case 2: return priceSize;
        case 4: return priceDays;
        case 5: return sideComps;
        case 6: return mappedHouses;
        case 9: return agentDetails;
        default: return null;
      }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to dynamically render the HTML of your `<div>` component collection (ie `priceSize`, `agentDetails`, etc) would  via a `switch` statement.

First, ensure that your HTML is defined as a valid component (ie leading capitalization):

```
var SubjectProperty = <div>HTML goes here</div>
var PriceSize = <div>HTML goes here</div>
var AgentDetails = <div>HTML goes here</div>
var MappedHouses = <div>HTML goes here</div>
var SideComps = <div>HTML goes here</div>
var PriceDays = <div>HTML goes here</div>
```

Next, update the component that renders the `report_sequence` array. One way to introduce the `switch` idea mentiond above would be via a locally defined method:

```
render() {

    /* Define a local helper that renders the component corresponding to
    a specific key  */
    const renderItem = (key) => {

      switch(key) {
        case 1: return <SubjectProperty/>;
        case 2: return <PriceSize/>;
        case 4: return <PriceDays/>;
        case 5: return <SideComps/>;
        case 6: return <MappedHouses/>;
        case 9: return <AgentDetails/>;
      }

      return null;
   }

   /* Invoke locally defined renderItem() method to dynamically render
   each list item based on item's key */
   return report_sequence.map((data) => 
       <div key={data.key} className={data.key}>
       { renderItem(data.key) }
       </div>)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Denney, It worked for me by doing minor changes like *default* should inside switch block and *SubjectProperty* etc. instead of  *<SubjectProperty/>* etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have yours components mocks:

```
var PriceSize = <div>HTML goes here</div>
var AgentDetails = <div>HTML goes here</div>
var MappedHouses = <div>HTML goes here</div>
var SideComps = <div>HTML goes here</div>
var PriceDays = <div>HTML goes here</div>
```

Here is map will render proper component

```
const componentMap = {
  [1]: () => <PriceSize />
  [2]: () => <AgentDetails /> 
  [3]: () => <MappedHouses /> 
  [4]: () => <SideComps /> 
  [5]: () => <PriceDays /> 
}
```

And here you have your render function and:

- When your render components dynamically you need to add `key` property do allow identifying them somehow by React, I assumed that you have some property like ID in this data set (can be index or anything unique)
- I assumed there is something like type in mapped data set which allows rendering proper component,
- In curly brackets I'm checking if map has some `value` for given `key` and if it is I call it.

Code:

```
render() {
      report_sequence.map((data) => 
        return (
          <div className={data.key} key={data.id}>
            {this.componentMap[data.type] && this.componentMap[data.type]()}
          </div>
        );
      )
    }
```